# Is "access review queues" privilege eligibility revised?

Tags: support, review

Few days ago I could access the First Posts and Late Answers review queues with a reputation of 350. But after the new site design rolled out it required [500 reputation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) to access the review queues.

Is the revision mentioned in any meta post? Or somewhere else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since [some while ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905/design-independent-graduation-is-on-for-early-september?s=3|4.6291), the graduation process changed and became design-independent.

When a site graduates, the reputation levels required for almost all the privileges are [increased](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2707/reputation-required-for-privileges?s=1|0.8041).

It was decided that the site graduation be announced first, and the privilege thresholds be raised after the design is ready. Well, the design is ready.

Comment: Oh, I'm not aware of it. Thanks for pointing out.